# Chat gets disconnect when iOS App goes into background mode

Tags: ios, web, background, uikit, chat

The iOS App I am working on has a Chat facility that works by running in a full-screen presented SFSafariViewController.

The problem is that when App is backgrounded, Chat is disconnected after 20 - 30 seconds. This is of course very annoying for all involved parties.

There is very little or no control at all over the Chat component except for using the Url specified to set up the Safari view controller.

I have considered trying to keep the App alive and preventing Chat to disconnect, by enabling some kind of background processing. But would like to seek advice before trying it out, as it seems to be a complex matter, and perhaps a bit of an overshoot since Chat facility is only a fraction of the entire app functionality.

Comment: Network connections are lost when an app moves to the background.  You will need to implement reconnection in your chat component.  You won't be able to keep the app alive in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by latest comment by Paul11.

Thus there are two possible solutions: 1) get chat component to reconnect when app is foregrounded, which is difficult as it is running in web. 2) Add  network background capability to app so it maintains network connection during background mode, which is an expensive solution as chat is not a big part of the app.